# change emoji key to ctrl in Microsoft designer keyboard with autohotkey

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, emoji

A few days ago I bought `Microsoft designer keyboard`

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/d/microsoft-designer-compact-keyboard/8zhrtr7zcswq?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

it has <kbd>emoji</kbd> key but it's not useful at all... so I decide to change it to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and the only application that I think can do it is `AutoHotkey`

When I check `view -> key history and script info` and I press <kbd>emoji</kbd> key I can see all these lines added:

```
A2  01D     d   3.08    LControl        
A0  02A     d   0.00    LShift          
A4  038     d   0.00    LAlt            
5B  15B     d   0.02    LWin            
20  039     d   0.00    Space           
20  039     u   0.09    Space           
A2  01D     u   0.00    LControl        
A0  02A     u   0.00    LShift          
A4  038     u   0.00    LAlt            
5B  15B     u   0.00    LWin
```

so I wrote this script but it's not working properly...

```
$~*<^<+<!<#space:: ; this line means: LControl+LShift+LAlt+LWin+Space
Send,{ctrl}
return
```

After running this script, every time I press the <kbd>emoji</kbd> key, Microsoft Office will be open. so this script is not working...

help me to get rid of this <kbd>emoji</kbd> key... I need the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key.

please write if you know any other application or any other way that I can convert <kbd>emoji</kbd> key to ctrl`.

Comment: This line looks truly horrendous `$~*<^<+<!<#space::`, what is it supposed to do? Anyway, for a solution, try to see if you can get the key's VK or SC and make a hotkey based off that. See [this](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys) documentation page for help.

Comment: @0x464e I update my question.... there is not one VK or SC or emoji key... when I press it I can see 10 lines added...

Comment: Ok, I see now. I posted an answer that might be of some help.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, seems your emoji key is implemented via sending <kbd>Office Key</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.
And the office key is implemented via the key combination <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>LShift</kbd>+<kbd>LAlt</kbd>+<kbd>LWin</kbd>.
Pressing <sub><sup>(and releasing without any other keypress in-between)</sup></sub> the office key alone takes you to https://www.office.com/?from=OfficeKey. You want to disable this behavior. Otherwise that website will get launched every time. Would make your remap pretty bad.
According to [this answer](https://www.office.com/?from=OfficeKey), you can disable it via a registry change.

After that, you should be able to remap <kbd>Office Key</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to something better:

```
^+!#Space::MsgBox, % "Hello!"
```

To properly remap to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, you need to take the down & up events into consideration.
This might do it:

```
^+!#Space::SendInput, {Ctrl Down}
^+!#Space Up::SendInput, {Ctrl Up}
```

But really I'm not sure. I don't have an office key, so I'm reluctant to make that registry change and try go figure it out more.

Answer (score 3):

for future visitors, I want to put the correct answer here because the correct answer is the combination of the two above answers thanks to [0x464e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813732/0x464e) and [spyre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14362191/spyre) I can't say one the answers is the correct so I just vote up both posts.

first, we should download [Microsoft's Mouse and Keyboard software](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/mouse-and-keyboard-center-download-f5b10905-7887-eedb-2f1c-d0737a36a3b2) and remap <kbd>emoji</kbd> key to <kbd>application</kbd> key ([what is application key](https://www.perkinselearning.org/technology/blog/using-applications-key-or-without-key#:%7E:text=On%20standard%2C%20full%2Dsized%20keyboards,the%20right%20side%20control%20key.))

after that, we should add these lines of code to AutoHotKey

```
AppsKey::SendInput, {Ctrl Down}
AppsKey Up::SendInput, {Ctrl Up}
```

and now <kbd>emoji</kbd> key works exactly like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and the combination like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> will select all the text.

thank the StackOverflow community. I can't imagine life without YOU.

Comment: Is that software not able to just remap it straight to `Ctrl`? Weird piece of software if it lets you remap to `AppsKey` but not `Ctrl`. But well, what do I know, maybe there's a good reason, I don't know how that software interfaces with those Microsoft keyboards.

Comment: No there are just 3 options for Emoji key:1- emoji 2- office 3- application key

Comment: Ok, well maybe they have some reason for it. Also, as a side note, there's no reason here to use a scan code hotkey, you can just use the key name `AppsKey`. (`AppsKey::` and `AppsKey Up::`)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like something you would be able to edit from [Microsoft's Mouse and Keyboard software](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/mouse-and-keyboard-center-download-f5b10905-7887-eedb-2f1c-d0737a36a3b2).

I personally have used it to remap the special keys on my Microsoft Comfort Curve Keyboard- it should be very similar for the other models of keyboards they manufacture.

Feel free to let me know if you need more specific instructions to change the function of the emoji keys to fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I read all the answers and all the comments but the only thing that helped me to disable my Emoji key was this code:

```
AppsKey::SendInput, {Ctrl Down}
AppsKey Up::SendInput, {Ctrl Up}
```